# Python Odd and Even

Tags: python

I am very new to python. I am trying to write a program that tests if a number is between a given range, then tells you if the number is odd or even. I am having trouble with the part that detects if it is odd or even. It seems that if it just repeats my even statement. Here is the code:

```
while True:
    num = int(input("Please enter an integer between 1 and 50: "))
    if num >= 1 and num <= 50:
        for num in range (1, 50):
            if (num % 2 == 0):
                print("Your number is even.")
        else:
            print("Your number is odd.")
        
    else:
        print("Try again. Number must be 1 through 50.")
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a `for` loop at all, and you forgot to indent the `else` part if your inner `if-else`:

```py
while True:
    num = int(input("Please enter an integer between 1 and 50: "))
    if num >= 1 and num <= 50:
        for num in range (1, 50):  # not needed
            if (num % 2 == 0):
                print("Your number is even.")
            else:  # here
                print("Your number is odd.")
    else:
        print("Try again. Number must be 1 through 50.")
```

`for-else` constructs exist (and are pretty neat), but it you're starting to learn Python, it's a story for another time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It sure is easy to overlook small things like that.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you don't need the `for` loop:

```
while True:
    num = int(input("Please enter an integer between 1 and 50: "))
    if 1 <= num <= 50:
        if num % 2 == 0:
            print("Your number is even.")
        else:
            print("Your number is odd.")        
    else:
        print("Try again. Number must be 1 through 50.")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need for loop, Remove for loop and try again.

```
while True:
num = int(input("Please enter an integer between 1 and 50: "))
if num >= 1 and num <= 50:
        if (num % 2 == 0):
            print("Your number is even.")
        else:  # here
            print("Your number is odd.")
else:
    print("Try again. Number must be 1 through 50.")
```